# How to parse Prometheus data

Tags: go, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, ebnf

I have been able to obtain the metrices by sending an HTTP GET as follows:

```
# TYPE net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total untyped net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total{dialer_name="federate",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"} 1 1608520832877
```

Now I need to parse this data and obtain control over every piece of data so that I can convert tand format like json.

I have been looking into the ebnf package in Go:
[ebnf package](https:///godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/ebnf)

Can somebody point me the right direction to parse the above data?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a nice package already available to do that and it's by the *Prometheus's Authors* itself.

They have written a bunch of Go libraries that are shared across *Prometheus* components and libraries. They are considered internal to Prometheus but you can use them.

Refer: [github.com/prometheus/common](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common) doc. There's a package called `expfmt` that can decode and encode the **Prometheus's Exposition Format** ([Link](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/)). Yes, it follows the *EBNF* syntax so `ebnf` package could also be used but you're getting `expfmt` right out of the box.

Package used: [expfmt](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common@v0.15.0/expfmt)

Sample Input:

```
# HELP net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total
# TYPE net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total untyped
net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total{dialer_name="federate",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"} 1 1608520832877
```

Sample Program:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    dto "github.com/prometheus/client_model/go"
    "github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt"
)

func fatal(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func parseMF(path string) (map[string]*dto.MetricFamily, error) {
    reader, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var parser expfmt.TextParser
    mf, err := parser.TextToMetricFamilies(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return mf, nil
}

func main() {
    f := flag.String("f", "", "set filepath")
    flag.Parse()

    mf, err := parseMF(*f)
    fatal(err)

    for k, v := range mf {
        fmt.Println("KEY: ", k)
        fmt.Println("VAL: ", v)
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
KEY:  net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total
VAL:  name:"net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total" type:UNTYPED metric:<label:<name:"dialer_name" value:"federate" > label:<name:"instance" value:"localhost:9090" > label:<name:"job" value:"prometheus" > untyped:<value:1 > timestamp_ms:1608520832877 >
```

So, `expfmt` is a good choice for your use-case.

Update: Formatting problem in OP's posted input:

Refer:

1. https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/issues/147#issuecomment-368215305
2. https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#command-line

```
Note that in the text protocol, each line has to end with a line-feed
character (aka 'LF' or '\n'). Ending a line in other ways, e.g. with 
'CR' aka '\r', 'CRLF' aka '\r\n', or just the end of the packet, will
result in a protocol error.
```

But from the error message, I could see `\r` char is present in in the put which is not acceptable by design. So use `\n` for line endings.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Run this program by building it (`go build`). Suppose the executable's name is `promfmt`, then run `./promfmt --f /path/to/file` where `/path/to/file` is the path (absolute or relative; both works!)

Comment: Add a newline char at the end of the file. In actual, there's a newline after the metric.

Comment: The file you posted has some formatting errors. Try using the file I used as input.

Comment: I've updated my answer. That should help!

Comment: is the script not supposed to ignore the line that start with # ?  Once i removed all the lines starting with #, and use the updated code from the answer, the error changed to " expected integer as timestamp, got "1608520832877\r"

Comment: No! Why it'll ignore the `#`. The type of metric is mentioned in `# TYPE`; look at the example I shared. The problem is with the format you have. You have `\r` endings which Prometheus parsers don't accept. Read my answer, again!